# How can I hide a tab group located on a ribbon in a Microsoft Office application?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, customization, ribbon

On the `Main Tabs -> Home (Mail) -> Add-ins` Office Ribbon there is an tab group called `Add-ins', which houses a tab called`Store`.

I would like to remove/hide this tab.  I do not see a way to do that as when I go to `Outlook Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Main Tabs -> Home (Mail)`, the menu item in the tree UI element is grayed out and is inaccessible for removal.

I have this issue in `Outlook`, which is apart of Microsoft Office Home and Business 2013 Version 15.0.4823.1004

Here is a visual, where you see the Add-in group that contains the Store tab, which I want to remove.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can block access to the Store in Office 2013 and 2016 using group policies. Please see https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/Cc178992.aspx#section1 for more information. Note that the term "Apps for Office" was the previous name for "Add-ins".